Django: Performing actions after an object is created or updated
I've got a model called EventMembership which determines whether someone is attending the event or not:-
class EventMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='eventmemberships')
    is_attending = models.BooleanField()

I also have an EventFee model which is used to track the user's fees for events:-
class EventFee(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='eventfees')
    amount = models.DecimalField()

If a user is attending the event, they should have a fee for that event's price. If not, they should not have a fee.
What is the best way for me to handle the creating, updating or deleting of these fees?
I've seen a lot of people warn against using signals and I have had problems with signals in the past but they seem like the perfect solution.
I suppose it's signals or override the save() method on the model, isn't it? But overriding the save() method would mean the fees get updated every time the model is saved which seems bad to me.
Any other suggestions?
Note: I'm using Django Rest Framework for this so these EventMemberships can be created, updated or deleted through that. But they can also be updated via a couple of other mechanisms, like a user deleting their account, for example - where all of their memberships for future events will be set to "not attending" so I'm not sure I should do the fee creation etc. in a serializer or a view.

signals are the best way

This is mostly an opinion question.  I would create them in the view, as a transaction.  And I would make it a single purpose APIView and not as part of a ModelViewSet.  This is not a single object create/update, and making it part of a very simple view means you can move the creation logic out and unit test it as well (not that you have to).

1- I see a missing field in EventFee model. According to your description EventFee will not exist unless there is an attached EventMembership. So I expect a foreign key there (could be replacing the user potentially which could be retrieved via the membership).
class EventFee(models.Model):
    membership = models.ForeignKey(EventMembership, related_name='eventfees', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount = models.DecimalField()

adding on_delete=models.CASCADE will ensure that the fees is deleted when membership is deleted.
2- Creating and updating the fees can simply be centralized in the EventMembershipSerializer by overriding create(when is_attending is true)/update(if is_attending changed) methods. This could be more straight forward to maintain if you want to avoid signals, and will give you some flexibility if you want to do this via EventFeeSerializer.
3-

I suppose it's signals or override the save() method on the model,
isn't it? But overriding the save() method would mean the fees get
updated every time the model is saved

if you go through the model you can compare the current and the new values for is_attending and check if the operation is for create or update (similar to the logic in point 2). This allows updating the fees only when needed.
